# How to reset the input value of the form when I change the input value?

Tags: javascript, forms, api

After I submit the form with the actor/actress name, and it lists the movies, if  I want to search again by typing another name, the first time that I click enter, it returns the same movies as the first search, and if I then again click enter with the new name typed in, it lists the movies by that actor/actress.So basically it lists the movies on every second submit(given that a name of the actor/actress changed). Is there a way around this? I tried adding `sessionStorage.clear()` in the form submit function, that doesn't work. I also tried `actor.value.clear()` but that clears the value of the form input and it doesn't list anything. Any help is much appreciated, thanks a lot in advance. Here's the code:

```
const form = document.getElementById("form");
form.addEventListener("submit", (e)=>{
    var actor = document.getElementById("actor").value;
    var byActor = document.getElementById("byActor");
    byActor.innerHTML = actor;
    discoverByActor(actor);
    moviesByActor();
    e.preventDefault();
})
function discoverByActor(actor){
    axios.get("https://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/person?api_key=<API_KEY>&language=en-US&query="+actor+'&page=1&include_adult=false')
        .then((response)=>{
            let actorId = response.data.results[0].id;
            sessionStorage.setItem("theActorId", actorId);
        })
};
function moviesByActor(){
    let actorId = sessionStorage.getItem("theActorId");
    axios.get("https://api.themoviedb.org/3/discover/movie?api_key=<API_KEY>&language=en-US&sort_by=popularity.desc&include_adult=false&include_video=false&page=1&with_people="+actorId)
        .then((response)=>{
            console.log(response);
            let movies = response.data.results;
            let output = "";

            $.each(movies, (index, movie)=>{
                output +=`
                <div class="card">
                        <img src="http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w300/${movie.poster_path}" onerror="this.onerror=null;this.src='../images/image2.png';">
                        <h3>${movie.title}</h3>
                        <p>${movie.vote_average} <strong>IMDB Rating</strong></p>
                        <p>Release date: <strong>${movie.release_date}</strong></p>
                        <a onclick="movieSelected('${movie.id}')" class="btn" href="#"> Movie Details </a>
                    </div>
                `
            })
            let moviesInfo = document.getElementById("movies");
            moviesInfo.innerHTML = output;
            //Display pages buttons.
            let pages = document.querySelector(".pages");
            pages.style.display = "flex";
            var actor = document.getElementById("actor");
        })
}
```

Comment: why are you storing it in `sessionStorage` ? I mean why do you need to do this  ?

Comment: Reset the value using document.getElementById('"actor").value =""; not clear()

Comment: George, I am storing the ID of the actor in sessionStorage, so I can use it so it shows the movies in which that particular actor plays. The API request for discover movies with_people (the 2nd request) uses the ID of the Actor (provided by the first API request) to list the movies in which he/she plays. I figured out that should be the way to go, but I might also be wrong since I'm pretty new to JavaScript(been learning on my own for about 3 weeks), because the first API request doesn't hold data about the movies themself, the second request can't link the movie to the actor. Only this way..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sessionStorage.setItem("theActorId", actorId);
```

doesn't happen until you have a response from `axios.get`.  However, you call `moviesByActor` before that, which does

```
let actorId = sessionStorage.getItem("theActorId");
```

What you probably want to do is:

```
form.addEventListener("submit", (e)=>{
    // ...
    discoverByActor(actor).then(moviesByActor);
    // ...
})

function discoverByActor(actor){
    return axios.get("https://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/person?api_key=<API_KEY>&language=en-US&query="+actor+'&page=1&include_adult=false')
    .then((response)=>{
        let actorId = response.data.results[0].id;
        sessionStorage.setItem("theActorId", actorId);
    })
};
```

Also, if you don't actually need `actorId` in the session, you could do:

```
form.addEventListener("submit", (e)=>{
    // ...
    discoverByActor(actor).then(moviesByActor);
    // ...
})

function discoverByActor(actor){
    return axios.get("https://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/person?api_key=<API_KEY>&language=en-US&query="+actor+'&page=1&include_adult=false')
    .then((response)=>{
        return response.data.results[0].id;
    })
};

function moviesByActor(actorId) {
    axios.get( /* ... */ );
    // ...
}
```

JavaScript has a concurrency model based on an "event loop".  A very interesting property of the event loop model is that JavaScript, unlike a lot of other languages, never blocks (with the exception of `alert` or synchronous XHR and I'm sure a few others).

`axios.get(url).then(doSomething)` is asynchronous, so when you do it, you are telling the computer "go fetch whatever is at this url, and *once you get a response*, send the response to doSomething.  In the meantime, though, keep running the rest of this code.

So when you did `discoverByActor(actor); moviesByActor();`, you were calling `moviesByActor` *even if* you hadn't received anything from `discoverByActor`.

Of course, it would be hard to program if you couldn't control the order that things happen, so to deal with this, we use what are called [`Promises`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise).

With a promise, we can say, go fetch this url using `axios.get`, `.then` use that result to do this other thing, `.then` use whatever *that* returns to do this other thing.

So, I had `discoverByActor` return `axios.get` so I could get access to the `.then` method, so that I could endure that `moviesByActor` would have the data that it needed to run.

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick, now its working as it's supposed to. Because I am still pretty new into JavaScript ( and programming languages overall) could you, if you have spare time, to explain to me why I had to put "discoverByActor(actor).then(moviesByActor)" in the form submit function and "return" infront of axios.get, in order to get it working?

Comment: Happy to! I just added some explanation, let me know if it makes more sense

Comment: Thanks a lot, I really appreciate it, it does make sense now. Thanks ! :D